# Jhipster delegating auth to keycloak: 'Bad request' occured only if keycloak.admin.client is installed

Tags: spring-boot, maven, keycloak, jhipster

I'm working on a project with springboot generated by jhipster.
I use Oauth2 authentication with keycloak.
Everything was working but after I added keycloak admin client in my pom.xml, I couldn't connect to my jhipster homepage with a success message anymore.

My error page :
[Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Oqq.png)

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 ...
<properties>
   <!-- Build properties -->
   <keycloak-starter.version>12.0.4</keycloak-starter.version>
   <keycloak-admin-client.version>12.0.4</keycloak-admin-client.version>
   <keycloak-adapter.version>12.0.4</keycloak-adapter.version>
 ...
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <!-- keycloak-maven-add-dependency-management -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak-adapter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
                <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency-management -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
 ...
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.4</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.4</version>
     </dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>
```

My application.dev.yml :

```
 ...
spring:
   ...
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/****
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: account
            client-secret: ********
   ...
server:
  port: 8080

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  cache: # Cache configuration
    ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
      max-entries: 100 # Number of objects in each cache entry
  # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
  cors:
    allowed-origins: '*'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
  mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
    base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  metrics:
    logs: # Reports metrics in the logs
      enabled: false
      report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
  audit-events:
    retention-period: 30 # Number of days before audit events are deleted.

# ===================================================================
# Application specific properties
# Add your own application properties here, see the ApplicationProperties class
# to have type-safe configuration, like in the JHipsterProperties above
#
# More documentation is available at:
# https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# application:
keycloak:
  realm: ****
  resource: account
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:9080/auth/
  credentials:
    secret: ********
```

My keycloak admin client config :
[keycloak admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcIWg.png)

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, in particular add the log of your spring boot app when the bad request occurs. Also explain what you are trying to achieve with keycloak admin client

Comment: That "bad request" screenshot is very vague. Open up your browser dev tools and see which HTTP request is failing and the error response, if there's any.

Comment: @XtremeBiker
[![browser Devtools][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StWf3.png

Comment: @GaëlMarziou 

[![spring boot log][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq3VO.png

As you can see there is no error displayed on the server

Comment: What about keycloak server logs?

Comment: @XtremeBiker

[![keycloak server logs][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS7u1.png

As you can see there are just warnings, no errors.

Comment: Have a look to the failing http response in the devtools

Comment: You could also run your app under java debugger and inspect variables when the error is triggered.